# Help me finding $a+b+c$ in the given question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

If $a,b,c$ are three positive integers such that $$abc+ab+bc+ca+a+b+c=1000$$ then what is the value of $a+b+c$?

Comment: $1000-abc-ab-bc-ca$?...

Comment: $a=6,b=10,c=12$ (since $7\cdot11\cdot13=1001$).

Comment: @barakmanos Or any combination of those.. Sum is 28 though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compute
$$
(a + 1)(b + 1)(c + 1) - 1 = \dots
$$

Comment: Was just about to post it! Beat me by seconds :)

Comment: @ArpanBanerjee, it happens to me all the time... ;-)